# How to exchange signals between applications?

Tags: java, spring

I have two unconnected applications. One is the main app that performs the business logic and CRUD on database.

A 2nd app periodically rebuilds a database cache (long running taks). I want to send a signal to the main app when the rebuild starts, and when it's finished, as the main app should take specific actions while rebuilding takes place.

How could I achive this best using `spring-boot`?

Comment: Sounds like a job for message queueing such as RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ.

Comment: I agree with the first poster. Read up on JMS

Comment: Is it possible to provide the broker by the main application itself? So that I don't have to install additional software, but the 2nd app can just send messages to the main app via JMS?

Comment: Somehow I feels adding eg ActiveMQ introduces a big memory overhead for just exchanging a simple message signal. At least I get: `ERROR org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService: Memory Usage for the Broker (1024 mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 989 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 692 mb`. Isn't there a more memory friendly solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using spring-boot you can use jms simply by adding active-mq dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

in yml config you would start the amq jms broker in one application by not specifying broker-url at all because spring.activemq.in-memory property defaults to true (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) 
or configuring it like this:

```
activemq:
    broker-url: failover:(vm://localhost:61616?connectionTimeout=3000)
```

and connect to it from the other application like this

```
activemq:
    broker-url: failover:(tcp://machineoftheotherapplication:61616?connectionTimeout=3000)
```

You might need to consider if you need your messages to use persistent reliable delivery, meaning if you send a message and the other application is not running it would get the message after it start up again.

Comment: Yes that would work, BUT as written above the activemq JMS introduces a too big memory overhead for just exchanging a simple message.

Comment: define 'too big memory overhead'

Comment: As commented above: `ERROR org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService: Memory Usage for the Broker (1024 mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 989 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 692 mb`. I don't want to give ma applicatio like 1GB+ memory.

Comment: what the 'error' message says is that the amq instance is configured (by default in your case) to use maximum 1GB of heap and because there isn't that much available in currently running jvm it changes it's config to 692 mb. it's not an error really. I am quite sure you don't need 1MB for exchanging a simple message. find a way to configure the amq memory limit if you want to get rid of the 'error' in the log.

Comment: Such a low memory usage would of course be OK. Do you think this still applies when starting activemq embedded (which I have to, as I cannot run an explicit activemq standalone).

Comment: yes, it does. if you don't configure the upper memory limit (I am not sure how to do this when running in spring boot), it will be set to 70% of the max heap available to your application. if there is some big traffic (which is not your case) amq will use up to 70% of the available heap for itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your application works with http requests you could just add a special controller which would process the requests from the second app. 
Another option would be a JMX request.
However, security should be considered.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the apps do not provide any http or webserver architecture. Just command line applications.

Comment: So how is `sping-boot` involved?

Comment: spring-data-jpa / repositories, database management, sockets to name a few.

Comment: The application does not have to have to run on a web server to use jmx